# Replace one value of array by more values and keep its the position order

Tags: php

Now I have

```
$data = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

$found = "green";
$expand1 = "apple";
$expand2 = "other";
if $data = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); //[1]=>"green"
I want get the new array look like this
$result = array("red", "apple","other", "blue", "yellow");

if $data = array("green", "blue", "yellow","red");//[0]=>"green" beginning
I want get the new array look like this
$result = array("apple","other", "blue", "yellow","red");


if $data = array("blue", "yellow","red","green");//[3]=>"green" the end
I want get the new array look like this
$result = array("blue", "yellow","red","apple","other");
```

Anyboday know the sulotion.please.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the php array splice function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

so...

```
$result = array_splice($data,1,1,array("apple","other"));
```

should do the trick.

Comment: in the case How can we replace the "green" by  "apple","other" and keep the order postion

Comment: $pos = array_sear($found,$data);
$result = array_splice($data,1,1,array("apple","other"));

Comment: Right, $pos = array_search("green",$data); $result = array_splice($data,$pos,1,array("apple","other"));   Would replace "green" in the $data array with "apple" and "other", making their indexes 1 and 2 respectively (and pushing other indexes back) in the new $result array.

Comment: There should be none with the array_splice function, though if you encapsulate the $pos = array_search function in an if/then statement (i.e. if($pos = array_search($needle, $haystack)) { ... do something .. }) the if statement will evaluate to 0 which it interprets as "false".  When dealing with array_search you would want to do a strict type check, so you would do if(array_search($n,$h) === false) as your check.   By itself array_splice($data,0,1,$array) should work just fine though.  If you have specific code post it here and I will take a look.